# Biblatex: Add cited "et al." authors to index

Tags: biblatex, indexing

I have references with long lists of authors.
I want to credit them all by listing them in the index,
but since I don't want to clutter my main text,
I display a maximum of two names in the citations.

How do I still add all co-authors to the index?

Here is my MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% Bibliography configuration
\usepackage[%
    maxcitenames=2, % cite: 1, 2, or 1st + et al.
    maxbibnames=99, % bib:  all authors
    indexing=cite   % put citations in index
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{database.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{database.bib}
@Article{BahOlsLat10,
  author            = {Bahador Bahrami and Karsten Olsen and
                       Peter E. Latham and Andreas Roepstorff and
                       Geraint Rees and Chris D. Frith},
  title             = {Optimally Interacting Minds},
  journal           = {Science},
  year              = {2010},
  volume            = {329},
  number            = {5995},
  pages             = {1081--1085},
  doi               = {10.1126/science.1185718}
}

@Book{BakEll11,
  author    = {Paul Baker and Sibonile Ellece},
  title     = {Key Terms in Discourse Analysis},
  year      = {2011},
  publisher = {Continuum International Publishing Group},
  isbn      = {978-1-8470-6320-5}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\textcite{BahOlsLat10,BakEll11}

\clearpage

\printbibliography

\printindex

\end{document}
```

**What happens:**
The two authors of the book both get listed in the index, but only the first author of the article with six authors.

**What I tried and does not work:**
Setting `indexing=true` will add all author names to the index, but the page numbers refer to the bibliography (here: page 2).
I want to have index entries of the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, ... authors pointing to where the citation was (here: page 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Biblatex documentation](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) on the `\indexnames` macro helped me out (which is called to add a list of names to the index):

> `\indexnames[<format>][<start>–<stop>]{<name list>}`
>
> This command is similar to `\printnames` ...

And for `\printnames` there is the crucial hint:

> If you want to override *maxnames* and *minnames* and force printing of the entire
> list, you may refer to the `listtotal` counter in the second optional argument:
>
> ```
> \printnames[...][-\value{listtotal}]{...}
> ```

So look for the original macro in [`biblatex.def`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/a96bcb92ba20ca8cfdbd2223beae3c697e5ce33e/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2679):

```latex
\newbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}}
```

And overwrite it your own code to make explicit that *all* entries from that list should be used:

```
\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\indexnames[][-\value{listtotal}]{labelname}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}}
```

Works like a charm.